# jquery ajax array null

Tags: jquery

I have no idea why the result array is empty after a successful ajax call. I am definitely getting the data back from the source url which is added to the array but the result is empty in return result statement.

Thanks for your help.

```
 function locationSearch(loc) {
    var result = [];
    $.ajax({
        data: 'q=description:' + loc + '*&wt=json&json.wrf=?&fl=*',
        url: 'http://deviis:8080/Locations/select/',
        aSync: false,
        success: function (data) {
            result.push({ value: "Any", data: "*" });
            $.each(data.response.docs, function (i, item) {
                result.push({ value: item.description, data: item.id });                    
            });               
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(data);`?

Comment: That's three wrong in less than a minute? Did anyone read the `aSync: false,` setting (allthough it should'nt be in camelcase) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try doing the return job inside the success callback. Always be aware of the closures in javascript programming.

John resig's answer to this [post](https://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/40d0e3def47148a0?pli=1) should help.

Answer (score 0):

you have places `return result;` outside of ajax `success` function, so you can't get the result. Because, it takes some time go get server response, but before that `locationSearch()` function return the `result` array which is empty.

**A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous.**

You can try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    result.push({ value: "Any", data: "*" });
    $.each(data.response.docs, function (i, item) {
        result.push({ value: item.description, data: item.id });                    
    }); 
    console.log(result);              
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the array shomehow right after you build it.

The ajax request might take longer and you are returning the empty array before the request is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using 'success: ' you are now able to use a *deferred promise* since jQuery 1.5 which allows this request to be processed asynchronously with a function such as .done();

See: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Also, if you are calling from a separate script file you will want to echo the result instead of returning it. As far as I can tell this is not what you are doing, but it would result in the same problem, so leaving that for others who may find this question.